# Assigning multiple python list elements in one go

Tags: python, matlab, vectorization, slice

Being familiar with the MATLAB programming language I'm looking for a convenient way to achieve the following assignment in python.

For a list *L*, given indices *I* and values *R*

```
    L = [10,20,30,40,50]
    I = [2,4,5]
    R = [200, 400, 500]
```

I want to assign these values in a similar manner to this

```
    L(I) = R
```

which should yield

```
    L == [10,200,30,400,500]
```

What is the python way of doing this? A copy of the original list would also be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for ndx, value in zip(I,R):
    L[ndx-1] = value
```

Answer (score 6):

Without `numpy`:

```
L = [10,20,30,40,50]
I = [1,3,4]
R = [200, 400, 500]

for i,j in enumerate(I):
    L[j] = R[i]

print L
```

Yields:

```
[10, 200, 30, 400, 500]
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're into using `numpy`:

```
    import numpy

    L = numpy.array([10,20,30,40,50])
    I = numpy.array([1,3,4])   # note the index difference (index by 0)
    R = numpy.array([200,400,500])
    L[I] = R
    print L
```

yields

```
    [ 10 200  30 400 500]
```

Comment: Ah great. Would this also work for other data types e.g. strings?

Comment: +1 for pointing out that MATLAB is index 1 based, and Python is index 0 based.

Comment: @knedlsepp, yes, you can create numpy arrays of type string, and do similar operations.

Answer (score 3):

**Basic non-`numpy` solution:**

You don't need `numpy` (although that is the better solution).  Here is a way to do it without `numpy`:

```
L = [10,20,30,40,50]
I = [2,4,5]
R = [200, 400, 500]

for i in range(len(I)):
        L[I[i]-1] = R[i]

print(L)
```

Gives you:

```
[10, 200, 30, 400, 500]
```

*NOTE*:  I did `I[i]-1` over `I[i]` because Matlab is base 1 where as Python is base 0.

**One liner solution:**

Here is a one liner (it creates a new list though):

```
L = [10,20,30,40,50]
I = [1,3,4]  #fixed indexes manually
R = [200, 400, 500]

NL = [R[I.index(x)] if x in I else L[x] for x in range(len(L))]

print(NL)
```

Results:

```
[10, 200, 30, 400, 500]
```